# I get lots of blue screens, graphics card drivers crashes and bootloops

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, bluescreenview

I recently built a new PC but I keep getting blue screens, graphics card driver crashes, and boot loops. I have reinstalled different windows versions (Home, Pro, Pro N) several times but it didn't help.

My system components are:

- Asus ROG STRIX B450-F Gaming
- AMD Ryzen 2700X
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 3200Mhz 2 x 16GB
- 2x Samsung 850 Evo 250GB
- Gigabyte RX 580 Gaming 8GB
- be quiet! Straight Power 11 650W

The blue screen errors are:

- irql_not_less_or_equal
- pfn_list_corrupt
- kmode_exception_not_handled
- kernel_security_check_failure

I use Windows 10 Pro N and the latest AMD drivers 20.1.3, I also tried 19.2.2, but there are the same problems. If I install the latest chipset drivers, it gets even worse, the picture often freezes, and the graphics card drivers crash even more frequently. I have boot loops relatively rarely and if I can end them with a reset. They arise when I am in Windows, then the computer suddenly goes out and boot loops

[Video of the bootloop](https://linustechtips.com/main/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=536214)

I don't know what to do, so I'm grateful for any help

And yes I have my ram installed in slot 2 and 4 and is d.o.c.p enabled.

Comment: Hello. What is your power supply? The RX580 need a good supply to prevent crashing.

Comment: Might just be worth checking and re-seating all components (CPU + Memory + GPU). You mention using latest chipset drivers, but have you made sure the BIOS is up to date? Also try disabling DOCP if reseating + BIOS update don't have any effect - At least one of those error codes is to do with memory issues.

Comment: I use a be quiet! Straight Power 11 650W I forgot to mention

Comment: Okay, thanks. If you tried all the steps that Smock told you, you can try using your PC with only your onboard video and see if the bootloop still occurs. If it doesn't, there's a chance the GPU has issues. If it still crashes, it might be a defective RAM stick.

Comment: And my BIOS version is 2501 but I had a bad experience with bios updates which is why I don't dare to update it.

Comment: I don't have an onboard video but will test my graphics card in another PC.

Comment: I also ran the windows 10 memory test "mdsched" which found no errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help I disabled d.o.c.p. and it now seems to work. Of course I still have to test my PC extensively, but now, of course, my RAM only runs at 2133Mhz RAM instead of 3200Mhz. Which causes me to lose some performance, so why can't I use d.o.c.p?

Comment: Because it crashes? Seriously though, the CPU contains the memory controller, and so it is not just the memory that needs to support the higher operating frequency. Your CPU lists support for DDR4-2933 max, so to get the higher memory freq, the CPU is overclocked. Overclocking tends to crash computers. If you disable DOCP, you can probably still manually adjuct settings to get higher clocks, but it looks like you will need to be satisfied with stock.

Comment: As @Yorik is pointing out.  ***OVERCLOCK*** is EXACTLY THAT.  Why do you think they call it OVERclocking?  You might get lucky and have hardware that will take the extra push.. you might not.  Generally when overclocking, I push it until my machine is doing what yours is now, then THEN BACK IT OFF until it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have now set 2933MHz manually and it works perfectly.